# Distribution of sum of two shifted Poisson

Tags: poisson-distribution

Suppose Y is shifted Poisson at "a", say Y -a ~Poisson (t) and X-b ~ Poisson (r), again a shifted Poisson at "b." Now what is the distribution of Z= X+ Y?

Any idea? How to prove it?

Comment: There are two parts to your question. First, $Z=(Y-a) + (X-b) + a + b$, so you only need to find out the distribution of the sum of two Poisson distributed random variables. This is easy to do if the two are independent.

Comment: @binkyhorse Given the nature of the question (which looks like it might be routine bookwork and should probably be tagged self-study), your comment strikes me as something you might reasonably post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, $Z-(a+b)=(Y−a)+(X−b)$, which is the sum of two Poisson distributed random variables. If $Y-a\sim\mathrm{Po}(t)$ and $X-b\sim\mathrm{Po}(r)$ are independent (which is the case if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent), their sum has a Poisson distribution with parameter $t+r$. In summary, $Z$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $t+r$ and is shifted by $a+b$. For a proof, you could use the moment generating function of the Poisson distribution.